# How to show table rows between two days?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a table. I want to show only table rows which match between two days

```
<table id ="Table">
 <thead>
<tr>
<th>Date</th>
<th>Name</th>
<th>Desc</th>
</tr>
 </thead>
  <tbody>
       <tr>
            <td> 20-06-2019</td>
            <td> Payment </td>     
            <td >ajay </td>
            <td>By cash</td>  
        </tr>
        <tr> 
            <td>21-06-2019</td>
            <td> Payment </td>     
            <td>ajay</td>
            <td>By Cash</td>
        </tr>
         <tr>

            <td>22-06-2019</td>
            <td>Payment </td>     
            <td>ajay </td>
            <td>Tran</td>
        </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>23-06-2019</td>
            <td> Payment </td>     
            <td class="table_account capitalize">ajay </td>
            <td>By cash</td>
        </tr>
</tbody>
   </table>
```

I want to show rows between date 20-6-2019 to 22-6-2019.

```
 20-6-2019 |Payment | Ajay | By cash| 
 21-6-2019 |Payment | Ajay |By cash |
 22-6-2019 |Payment | Ajay |Tran    |
```

Comment: you can control what you can show via php if this comes from a database of some sort. if this html table is hardcoded, you can do it in javascript as well. you'll need to start coding though

Comment: what you have tried so far to get your desired result? Also from where you got those 2 dates? user will input them via some search form or they are hard-coded?

Comment: Where does the filtering needs to happen ? server side in PHP or client side in javascript ? Does the filtering happen on user interaction ?

Comment: actually, data is coming from server-side. but I want to filter on   client-side javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your data is getting from server , you should hidden table first by css . Then get data and send to javascript function as param I test with `displayInterval` as below

```js
function displayInterval(from, to) {
  $("#Table tbody tr td:first-child").each(function() {
    var curDate = setJsDate($(this).html());
    var froms =setJsDate(from);
    var tos = setJsDate(to);
    if(curDate >= froms && curDate <= tos) {     
    } else {
      $(this).parent().hide();
    }
  });
  $("#Table tbody").show();
}
function setJsDate(d) {
 if(typeof d == "number" || typeof d == "undefined") return;
   var pattern = d.split('-');
   var dt = new Date(pattern[2]+"-"+pattern[1] + "-"+pattern[0]);
   return dt.getTime();
}
displayInterval('20-06-2019','22-06-2019');
```

```css
#Table tbody {
display : none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id ="Table">
 <thead>
<tr>
<th>Date</th>
<th>Name</th>
<th>Desc</th>
</tr>
 </thead>
  <tbody>
       <tr>
            <td>20-06-2019</td>
            <td> Payment </td>     
            <td >ajay </td>
            <td>By cash</td>  
        </tr>
        <tr> 
            <td>21-06-2019</td>
            <td> Payment </td>     
            <td>ajay</td>
            <td>By Cash</td>
        </tr>
         <tr>

            <td>22-06-2019</td>
            <td>Payment </td>     
            <td>ajay </td>
            <td>Tran</td>
        </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>23-06-2019</td>
            <td> Payment </td>     
            <td class="table_account capitalize">ajay </td>
            <td>By cash</td>
        </tr>
</tbody>
   </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        <table id ="Table">
 <thead>
<tr>
<th>Date</th>
<th>Name</th>
<th>Desc</th>
</tr>
 </thead>
  <tbody>
       <tr>
            <td> 20-06-2019</td>
            <td> Payment </td>     
            <td >ajay </td>
            <td>By cash</td>  
        </tr>
        <tr> 
            <td>21-06-2019</td>
            <td> Payment </td>     
            <td>ajay</td>
            <td>By Cash</td>
        </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>22-06-2019</td>
            <td>Payment </td>     
            <td>ajay </td>
            <td>Tran</td>
        </tr>
</tbody>
   </table>
```